# Handling nulls with json Play

Tags: scala, playframework, play-json

I am trying to parse json with null values for some fields using Play library. There is a case class which represents the data:

```
case class Id(value: Int) extends AnyVal

case class Name(value: String) extends AnyVal

case class Number(value: Int) extends AnyVal

case class Data(id: Option[Id], name: Option[Name], number: Option[Number])
```

Here is how parsing currently works:

```
def parse(jsValue: JsValue): Try[Seq[Data]] = Try {
    jsValue.as[JsArray].value
      .flatMap { record =>
        val id = Id((record \ "id").as[Int])
        val name = Name((record \ "name").as[String])
        val number = Number((record \ "number").as[Int])

        Some(Data(Some(id), Some(name), Some(number)))
      }
  }
```

Parsing with specific data types doesn't handle null cases, so this implementation returns:

```
Failure(play.api.libs.json.JsResultException: JsResultException(errors:List((,List(JsonValidationError(List(error.expected.jsstring),WrappedArray()))))))
```

For the input data like this:

```
{
    "id": 1248,
    "default": false,
    "name": null,
    "number": 2
  }
```

I would like to have something like this: `Seq(Data(Some(Id(1248)), None, Some(Number(2))))`

I am going to write the data into the database so I do not mind writing some null values for these fields.

How can I handle null values for fields in parsed json?

Comment: Does your JSON contain a trailing comma following the last key/value pair?

Comment: No, it does not. It is accidental

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply let the play-json library generate the `Reads` for your case classes instead of writing them manually:

```
import play.api.libs.json._

object Data {
  implicit val reads: Reads[Data] = {
    // move these into the corresponding companion objects if used elsewhere...
    implicit val idReads = Json.reads[Id]
    implicit val numberReads = Json.reads[Number]
    implicit val nameReads = Json.reads[Name]

    Json.reads[Data]
  }
}

def parse(jsValue: JsValue): Try[Seq[Data]] = Json.fromJson[Seq[Data]](jsValue).toTry
```

That way, your code will work even in case you change the arguments of your case classes.

If you still want to code it manually, you can use the `readNullable` parser:

```
val name: Option[Name] = Name(record.as((__ \ "name").readNullable[String]))
```

---

Note, however, that using `Try` is somewhat frowned upon in FP and directly using JsResult would be more idiomatic.

Answer (score -1):

If you are not locked to use play-json then let me show how it can be done easily with [jsoniter-scala](https://github.com/plokhotnyuk/jsoniter-scala):

```
import com.github.plokhotnyuk.jsoniter_scala.core._
import com.github.plokhotnyuk.jsoniter_scala.macros._

implicit val codec: JsonValueCodec[Seq[Data]] = JsonCodecMaker.make(CodecMakerConfig)

val json: Array[Byte] = """[
  {
    "id": 1248,
    "default": false,
    "name": null,
    "number": 2
  }
]""".getBytes("UTF-8")
val data: Seq[Data] = readFromArray(json)
println(data)
```

That will produce the following output:

```
List(Data(Some(Id(1248)),None,Some(Number(2))))
```

[Here](https://github.com/plokhotnyuk/play/pull/6/files) you can see an example how to integrate it with the Play framework.

Comment: Well, it would not work for me as I have to use only play-json.